# async function over a list

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-5.0

I Have a function that looks like this:

```
public async Task<decimal> GoToWeb(string Sym){}
```

what's the best way to call it over a list of strings?

Comment: Do you want to attempt to start all tasks at once, or do you want a maximum number of active tasks?

Comment: I want them done as fast as possible. since they are web queries, i think the best way would be to start them all as soon as possible.

Comment: OTOH, if they all go the same server, and that server allows a maximum number of concurrent connections, attempting to start all tasks at once may result in errors. Browsers commonly have a limit on the number of connections per server. If that issue doesn't arise, sure, start them all.

Comment: it doesn't, evidently...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh696703%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) an article from MSDN on using `async-await` to process multilpe tasks in parallel.  And [here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556530%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) another that specifically addresses a collection of tasks.

In short, you can do one of the following:

1. Start all of your tasks and then `await` each of them.  They will all run in parallel and your program will continue once they all complete.
2. Put your tasks into a collection and then use `await`[`Task.WhenAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160374%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) to wait for multiple tasks.

An example of the second method would be as follows:

```
List<string> Syms = ... // Create your list of strings
IEnumerable<Task<decimal>> tasks = from Sym in Syms select GoToWeb(Sym);
decimal[] results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```