# Reactive Extensions Observable from a collection of web queries 

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, async-await, c#-5.0

relevant:
[async function over a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783479/async-function-over-a-list)

I Have a function that looks like this:

```
public async Task<decimal> GoToWeb(string Sym){}
```

I want to call it periodically over a list of string once a minute.
How can I convert this into a Reactive Extensions Observable?

Comment: So what do you want to do with the N generated tasks each minute?

Comment: @JamesManning I wanted to poll a number of services over the web, asynchronously and handle the results as they come... Task is not the same as thread, so I think it is a valid approach, though i ended up doing something a bit different...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the reactive framework can handle the asynchrony for you you could try this:

```
var syms = new List<string>() { "ANZ", "BHP", };

var query =
    from i in Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
    from sym in syms.ToObservable()
    from d in GoToWeb(sym).ToObservable()
    select new
    {
        Symbol = sym,
        Value = d,
    };
```

You'll need to add a reference to the namespace `System.Reactive.Threading.Tasks` to get the `ToObservable()` extension for tasks.

Does this meet your needs?

Comment: For the Rx noobs among us, could you explain why you do ToObservable on the list?

Comment: @JamesManning - Since `syms` is a enumerable it can't be used in a query with observables unless you convert it to an observable itself. Calling `.ToObservable()` just turns the `IEnumerable<string>` into an `IObservable<string>`. Similarly, it also can turn a `Task<decimal>` into an `IObservable<decimal>`. Once everything is observable then you can perform the select many query.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an Rx noob, so there's likely a better option, but without knowing what you want to happen for each completed batch of web calls, I avoided using the linq syntax (even though I prefer using it when possible).

I did this in LINQPad using the NuGet package for Rx-Main(Prerelease)

[image]

```
void Main()
{
    var eachMinuteSequence = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

    var symbols = new[] { "GOOG", "MSFT", "AAPL" };

    Action<long> eachMinuteAction = async _ =>
    {
        var tasks = StartWebCalls(symbols);
        var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        // do something with the results
    };
    eachMinuteSequence.Subscribe(eachMinuteAction);
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public Task<decimal>[] StartWebCalls(IEnumerable<string> stockSymbols)
{
    return (
        from symbol in stockSymbols
        select GoToWeb(symbol)
    ).ToArray();
}

public async Task<decimal> GoToWeb(string Sym){throw new NotImplementedException();}
```